# Example of commutative algebra over integers where there exists $x$ such that $x = y^2$ for several $y$'s

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is there a commutative algebra over integers such that there exists $x$ with $x = y^2$ for several $y$'s?

Also, is there a commutative algebra over integers such that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $x$ in the algebra such that there exists a set $Y$ of cardinality $k$ of the elements $y$ that satisfy $x = y^2$?

Beside a polynomial example, would there be any monomial or numerical example?

Comment: What's the difference between a monomial and polynomial example? What do you mean by a "numerical" example, if not a subring of $\Bbb C$? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in $R=\Bbb Z[x_j,y_{i,j}]_{i\le j}/(x_j-y_{i,j}^2)_{i\le j}$ we have $x_j=y_{i,j}^2$ for $1\le i\le j$.

You won't get any numerical example, since nothing can have $>2$ square roots in a domain.

Comment: Some curiosity: how is domain associated with numerical examples? Isn't domain just all about $ab = 0$ leading to either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$?

Comment: @Kreep I assumed by numerical you at the very least meant a subring of $\Bbb C$. If you're telling me that's not the case, then define what you mean by "numerical." Also answer my first question: what's the difference between a monomial and polynomial example? Define your terms. It's extremely frustrating when you don't.

Comment: Does every value of $k$ occur in this construction? I think that  you also have $(-y_{i,j})^2=x_j$, so there may be an even number of solutions here. A possible remedy would be to go to characteristic two, where you get rid of the sign ambiguity :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Actually I think I could just take $\Bbb Z[x,y_i]/(x-y_i^2)$, since if there exists $>k$ such $y$ then there exists $k$ such $y$. If OP indeed wants strictness, then they'd have to either take away "over the integers" or restrict to even $k$ as you note.